# Context issue not resolve

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am working in a project in which i have to appear a dialog after every 30 seconds even if application is running or not as per the requirements of the project so i started the background thread to handle this dialog in Splash Screen Activity. But when the Main Activity Launches then previous activity destroyed now the problem is that when i call dialog.show(); the application crashed unexpectedly and when i read the exception it was that unable to add window android.os.BinderProxy is not valid. is your activity running ?
Can anybody please help me ?

```
SplashScreen Activity
_Thread = new MyThread(SplashScreen.this);
        _Thread.run("UI Thread");

MyThread Class

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(10*1000);
                            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Log.d("PopUp", "Before Function Calling");
                                    Alert = new MyAlert(activity);
                                    Alert.PopUpNotofication();
                                    Log.d("PopUp", "Function Called");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            }
        };
        thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();


MyAlert Class

public void PopUpNotofication()
    {
        Log.d("PopUp", "Inside Function");
        builder.setTitle("Submit Your Response");
        builder.setMessage("Bla bla");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Message.message(context, "Ok");
            }
        });
        Log.d("PopUp", "Setted Positive Button");
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Message.message(context, "No");
            }
        });
        Log.d("PopUp", "Setted Negative Button");
        dialog = builder.create();
        Log.d("PopUp", "Dialog Created");
        dialog.show();
        Log.d("PopUp", "Function Completed");
    }
```

Comment: Add some code you are explaining about !

Comment: **"...even if application is running or not"** : This pretty much breaks all design patterns for a UX. If a user has left your app why should they have to experience your dialog continuously appearing every 30 seconds?

Comment: i have written 30 seconds but its not. dialog will appear at most 5 to 6 times in a day. but thread will work after every 30 second

Answer (score 0):

From your description the problem looks like you have passed the activity context to your background thread, and by the time thread got access to the context the activity is destroyed making context as null giving you a null pointer exception.

From your requirements

> even if application is running or not as per the requirements

As per the developer guidelines you should use services for any task which out lives the life cycle of an acticity